# How to create a list of months in DolphinDB?

Tags: dolphindb

I need to generate a list containing all months between Jan 2020 and Jan 2023,

The result should be as follows:

`[2020.01, 2020.02, ..., 2023.01]`

How can I get this in DolphinDB?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches:

`2020.01M..2025.03M`

`seq(2020.01M,2025.03M)`